# Scroll multiple items in RecyclerView at the same time like carousel

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, carousel

I would like to use RecyclerView like a carousel for display 3 items at the same time on the screen.

So first, on the the screen, it display the items #1 #2 and #3.
When I swipe the RecyclerView (like a ViewPager) I would like to display items #4 #5 et #6 like this :

- The first screen

[image]

- The screen after the scroll

[image]

How to achieve this workflow ? Thanks you for your help !

Here is my *Activity*

```
public class CarouselActivity extends BaseActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
protected int getLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.carousel_activity;
}

@Override
protected void setupViews()
{
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<CarouselItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add(new CarouselItem());
    items.add(new CarouselItem());
    items.add(new CarouselItem());
    items.add(new CarouselItem());
    items.add(new CarouselItem());
    items.add(new CarouselItem());


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CarouselAdapter(context,activity,items));
}
}
```

And my *Adapter*

```
public class CarouselAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

protected ArrayList<CarouselItem> listItems;

protected Context context;
protected Activity activity;
protected LayoutInflater inflater;

public CarouselAdapter(Context context,
                       Activity activity,
                       ArrayList<CarouselItem> listItems)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
    this.listItems = listItems;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return listItems.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.carousel_item, parent, false);

    return new ItemHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position)
{
    ItemHolder itemHolder = (ItemHolder)holder;

    itemHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().width = ScreenHelper.getScreenWidthRatio(activity,33);
    itemHolder.itemView.getLayoutParams().height = ScreenHelper.getScreenWidthRatio(activity,50);

    itemHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor((position % 2 == 0 ) ? Color.RED : Color.BLUE);

    int page = position + 1;
    itemHolder.tvPage.setText("" + page);
}

protected static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private TextView tvPage;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        tvPage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_page);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think this would help https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SnapHelper.html...

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/using-snaphelper-in-recyclerview-fc616b6833e8

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47580753/14632246
Please have a look, might help